# How does BREACH attack work

Tags: django, security, csrf

So, I was reading about the security issues in Django websites. There I came to know about BREACH attack, which I have not understood completely. There it says that the attacker guesses the csrf token one character at a time and the response's compression ratio is increased when the character matches(But how??). This way, all the token can be guessed in short time.
Please could anyone explain about how this works in a simple manner.
Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [security.se]

Comment: Check [this](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/aug/06/breach-and-django/) and links in it for details.